# Removing stopwords from file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to remove stopwords from the Data column in my file.
I filtered out the line for when the end-user is speaking.
But it doesn't filter out the stopwords with the `usertext.apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stop_words])`
what am i doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from stop_words  import get_stop_words
df = pd.read_csv("F:/textclustering/data/cleandata.csv", encoding="iso-8859-1")
usertext = df[df.Role.str.contains("End-user",na=False)][['Data','chatid']]
stop_words = get_stop_words('dutch')
clean = usertext.apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stop_words])
print(clean)
```

Comment: first can you 1) print `stop_words`, 2) try `clean = usertext.apply(lambda x: [])` to see if it removes all words? (just to test)

Comment: Data      []
chatid    []
dtype: object
['aan', 'al', 'alles', 'als', 'altijd', 'andere', 'ben', 'bij', 'daar', 'dan', 'dat', 'de', 'der', 'deze', 'die', 'dit', 'doch', 'doen', 'door', 'dus', 'een', 'eens', 'en', 'er', 'ge', 'geen', 'geweest', 'haar', 'had', 'heb', 'hebben', 'heeft', 'hem', 'het', 'hier', 'hij', 'hoe', 'hun', 'iemand', 'iets', 'ik', 'in', 'is', 'ja', 'je', 'kan', 'kon', 'kunnen', 'maar', 'me', 'meer', 'men', 'met', 'mij', 'mijn', 'moet', 'na', 'naar', 'niet', 'niets', 'nog', 'nu', 'of', 'om', 'omdat', ...] This is the output of both

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regex pattern of your stop words and call the vectorised `str.replace` to remove them:

```
In [124]:
stop_words = ['a','not','the']
stop_words_pat = '|'.join(['\\b' + stop +  '\\b' for stop in stop_words])
stop_words_pat

Out[124]:
'\\ba\\b|\\bnot\\b|\\bthe\\b'

In [125]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['a to the b', 'the knot ace a']})
df['text'].str.replace(stop_words_pat, '')

Out[125]:
0         to  b
1     knot ace 
Name: text, dtype: object
```

here we perform a list comprehension to build a pattern surrounding each stop word with `'\b'` which is a break and then we `or` all words using `'|'`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

First, you have a module called `stop_words` and you later create a variable named `stop_words`. This is bad form.

Second, you are passing a lambda-function to `.apply` that wants its `x` parameter to be a list, rather than a value within a list.

That is, instead of doing `df.apply(sqrt)` you are doing `df.apply(lambda x: [sqrt(val) for val in x])`.

You should either do the list-processing yourself:

```
clean = [x for x in usertext if x not in stop_words]
```

Or you should do the apply, with a function that takes one word at a time:

```
clean = usertext.apply(lambda x: x if x not in stop_words else '')
```

As @Jean-François Fabre suggested in a comment, you can speed things up if your stop_words is a set rather than a list:

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words

nl_stop_words = set(get_stop_words('dutch'))    # NOTE: set

usertext = ...
clean = usertext.apply(lambda word: word if word not in nl_stop_words else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clean = usertext.apply(lambda x:  x if x not in stop_words else '')
```

Comment: if that works, I suggest to use a `set` for `stop_words` to gain efficiency.

Comment: i get NameError: ("name 'word' is not defined", 'occurred at index Data') when i run it

Comment: @DataNewB sorry it should be x